# Ruby round Float up or down to specific decimal significant figure

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding, floor, ceil

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1, and here's what I *want* to be able to do:

```
1.33333333.ceil(2) -> 1.34
1.33333333.floor(3) -> 1.333
```

The `Float#round` method allows me to *round*, but I need to be able to specify if I want to round up or down, similar to the `#ceil` and `#floor` methods, but with a parameter to specify how many decimal places to keep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Ruby 2.4+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-floor), the `Float#float` & `Float#ceil` methods take a `ndigits` argument:

```
1.33333333.ceil(2) -> 1.34
1.33333333.floor(3) -> 1.333
```

**However**, check out this behavior with those STD lib methods:

```
# In Ruby 2.4.2:
0.07.ceil(2) -> 0.08
1.1.ceil(2) -> 1.11
```

Not OK in my book.

For older Ruby versions or if you want to get better results than the STB lib gives, you will need to write your own methods. There are a few different blog posts out there, and I'll explain why they're not consistently correct later, but here are some methods that should work correctly every time:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

class Float
  def ceil2(exp = 0)
    BigDecimal(self.to_s).ceil(exp).to_f
  end

  def floor2(exp = 0)
    BigDecimal(self.to_s).floor(exp).to_f
  end
end
```

---

Now for more on why **the following are incorrect**:

```
def ceil_to(x)
  (self * 10**x).ceil.to_f / 10**x
end

def floor_to(x)
  (self * 10**x).floor.to_f / 10**x
end

# These methods also produce bad results for the examples shown above
0.07.ceil(2) -> 0.08
1.1.ceil(2) -> 1.11
```

I won't go into the details about what is happening (you can find that 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)), but floating point arithmetic can be messy and rounding errors do occur.